404 Unknown interaction error caused when attempting to sync commands in Discord.py
I receive a 404 Unknown Interaction error when running the following command:
@vot.event
@bot.tree.command(name='synx', description='expiremental sync')
@app_commands.checks.has_any_role(1024396774955298909, 1249016717032820770, 1309514819245834360)
async def sync(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await bot.tree.sync()
    print('Command tree synced expirementaly')
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Command tree synced expirementaly, {interaction.user.mention}', ephemeral=True)


This is the error output I receive when running the command:
> 2 commands has been synced succsesfully
Command tree synced expirementaly
2024-11-22 22:22:52 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'synx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lazorzneq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 858, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\lazorzneq\Documents\Project.Discord\Swift Blink\Welcome.py", line 38, in sync
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Command tree synced expirementaly, {interaction.user.mention}', ephemeral=True)
  File "C:\Users\lazorzneq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 855, in send_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\lazorzneq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 221, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lazorzneq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1310, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\lazorzneq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 883, in _invoke_with_namespace    
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lazorzneq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 876, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'synx' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

The purpose of this command is to sync all of the slash commands.

A 404 with Unknown interaction is usually because your code doesn't respond to the interaction within the statutory 3 second window without deferring.
In your scenario, await bot.tree.sync() is likely taking longer than this 3 second window and the token of the interaction you're trying to add a message response to is now invalid.
If you expect this processing to take 3 seconds or longer on a routine basis, defer() the interaction response and replace interaction.response.send_message() with interaction.followup.send():
@bot.tree.command(name='synx', description='expiremental sync')
@app_commands.checks.has_any_role(1024396774955298909, 1249016717032820770, 1309514819245834360)
async def sync(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True, thinking=True)
    await bot.tree.sync()
    print('Command tree synced expirementaly')
    await interaction.followup.send(f'Command tree synced expirementaly, {interaction.user.mention}', ephemeral=True)


Thank you so much for that! Also, I'm wondering if there's a way to make this command hybrid, so it could be called not only as a slash-command, could you please help with that?

Also, could you give me some help on error handeling, so console does not get spammed after someone, who does not have specific roles tries to input this command?

I would encourage you to ask a new question for each of these ([ask]) since they’re materially different from your current question
